# Duration of the contents in survey

Tags: python, survey, psychopy, psychtoolbox, google-surveys

I want to create a survey and add some images for target group. However this images should show only 2 seconds. Can anyone give me any advice for making this ? How can I do this ? Which program can I use or can I find any example PsychoPy code ? Thank you all.

Comment: Have you looked into survey tools such as [LimeSurvey](https://www.limesurvey.org/)?  Related [Q&A in LimeSurvey](https://www.limesurvey.org/forum/can-i-do-this-with-limesurvey/100271-display-one-picture-on-a-page-for-20-seconds)

Comment: I looked google forms and monkey surveys but they cannot do what i want. Thank you , I will.

Comment: @OğuzhanKırlar--in that case Limesurvey may be the way to go.  You can use the free tier for typical projects.  Added functionality like you describe is possible through Javascript with an active community that can help with suggestions.